# create sine wave with sox without a gap

Tags: linux, sox

i am using sox for creating synth with 100ms, this is my command:

```
/usr/bin/sox -V -r 44100 -n -b 64 -c 1 file.wav synth 0.1 sine 200 vol -2.0dB
```

now when i create 3 sine wave files and i combine all with

```
/usr/bin/sox file1.wav file2.wav file3.wav final.wav
```

then i get gaps between the files. i dont know why. but when i open for example file1.wav then i also see a short gap in front and at the end of the file.

how can i create a sine with exact 100ms without gaps in front and end?

and my 2nd question: is there also a possibility to create e.g. 10 sine wave synths with one command in sox? like sox f1 200 0.1, f2 210 01, f3 220 01, ... first 200hz 10ms, 210hz 10ms, 220hz 10ms

thank you so much many greets

i have tried some different options in sox but always each single sine file looks like that:

[image: WAV GAP]